# Synchronising One Drive on two machines each with its own password

Tags: onedrive

I have a One Drive account on PC which I access via a Hotmail Password, and another on a laptop which I access using a GMail password.

I thought One Drive was just that and no matter where I used it from, files would get dumped to One Drive.

Apparently not!

How do I synchronize the two so that any file saved in one is available in the other?

Comment: OneDrive sees one account linked to Hotmail, and another linked to Gmail. How can it know these are used by the same person?

Comment: You have two OneDrive accounts, what is your question, because it is t clear

Answer (score 1):

Use the same OneDrive account for both the PC and the laptop, and it will work exactly as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it seems you actually have two OneDrive accounts. Pick an account and use that account's username and password with both computers.